# ionic 2 vertical alignment using ion-grid

Tags: flexbox, ionic2

I have 2 buttons in a screen in Ionic 2, and I want to align them both together (one on top of the other, but together) in the middle of the screen (horizontal and vertical alignment).

I want to use ion-grid, no paddings, margins, floats or percentages.

So I have this

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col text-center>
        <button>button 1</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col text-center>
        <button>button 2</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

With `<ion-col text-center>` I can align them to the center horizontally, but for vertical alignment I can´t see anything that I can apply to , so I tried this:

```
ion-grid {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

But nothing happened.
I checked and this is being applied to the page, but for some reason it doesn´t work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Vote up for the `text-center` that solved my issue with horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use this:

```
ion-grid {
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: That works! I thought flex already took care about this. Why do I need to specify the height  if ion-grid is already a flex container?

Comment: Why the ion-row doesn't take the `ion-grid` height and stretch ?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the code below in a column (e.g.: flex-col) inside ion-grid to align centered vertically and horizontally:

```
.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a bit more of Ionic if you do it this way, and then just apply the height in your Sass files.  You also don't need the `ion-col`.  Also, the classes have changed and are just `.grid` and `.row`

**Markup**

```
  <ion-content>

    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>

        Horizontally and Vertically Centered

      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

  </ion-content>
```

**Sass**

```
.grid, .row {
  // Force grid to fill height of content as this is not set by default
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: align-items-center works fine, but justify-content-center shows no effect

Comment: Ionic CSS attributes are deprecated from Ionic 5. Therefore `<ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>` needs to be replaced with `<ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center ion-align-items-center">`