# Vertical alignment for ion-badge

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this `ion-item` in my Ionic 3 application. It includes an `ion-badge` and an `ion-button`. I want them both to be vertically aligned inside the `ion-item`. I tried the answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068980/ionic-2-vertical-alignment-using-ion-grid), but it didn't work. At the end I need to have these `ion-badge` and `ion-button` side by side.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-badge>150</ion-badge>
  <button ion-button>My Button</button>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your `ion-item`.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item class="my-item">
  <ion-badge>150</ion-badge>
  <button ion-button>My Button</button>
</ion-item>
```

And add the following CSS-styles to the `ion-label` child of your `ion-item`.

**SCSS:**

```
.my-item {
    ion-label {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: baseline
    }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Code and result with icon added to the button:

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item class="my-item">
    <ion-badge>150</ion-badge>
    <button ion-button icon-end>My Button
        <ion-icon name="arrow-down"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-item>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.my-item {
    ion-label {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: baseline
    }

    ion-icon {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}
```

Also i added a CSS-rule for the `<ion-icon>` to get som space between the text and the icon in the button.

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Like I said, it is working fine for this specific simplified settings. For example, if we put an icon inside the button like `<button ion-button><ion-icon name='arrow-down'></ion-icon></button>`, it won't work.

Comment: Ops, I meant the button and the badge would no longer remain vertically aligned.

Comment: Adding an icon to the button doesn't break anything for me. If you want you can delete your old comments on this answer, to keep things tidy. I went ahead and deleted my comments :)

Answer (score 0):

justify-content: center; will be work!!

```
ion-badge {justify-content: center; }
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align` to the styling:

```
<ion-badge style="vertical-align: bottom;">150</ion-badge>
```